# SAS and Oracle error: ORA-04031

Tags: sql, oracle, buffer, sas

I am using an ORACLE db with SAS/connect.
I recently implemented a change in my libname statement (a week ago) in which I added the following (don't know if related to issue):

```
insertbuff=10000 updatebuff=10000 readbuff=10000
```

Starting yesterday, I have been having an ORACLE issue when, after doing a

```
proc sql;
drop table oralib.mytable;
quit;

data oralib.mytable;
set work.mytable;
run;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: ERROR: ERROR: ORACLE execute error: ORA-04031: unable to
>   allocate 4160 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","unknown 
>          object","sga heap(1,0)","modification ").        With the occurrence of the above ERROR, the error limit of 1 set by the 
>          ERRLIMIT= option has been reached. ROLLBACK has been issued(Any Rows processed after the last COMMIT are lost).
>
> ```
>   Total rows processed: 1001 
>   Rows failed         : 1
> ```

It seems to happen randomly on any table of any size. Sometimes it will go through, sometimes (most of the times) it won't. Is there a shared pool release I should do from SAS?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared pool is a memory structure on Oracle which keeps the following stuff:

- data dictionary cache
- SQL query and PL/SQL function result caches
- storage for recently executed code in its parsed form

It is possible to flush the shared pool, but this is not a good idea and I would not recommend it. What you have to do is size the shared pool of the database properly. Note that the shared pool is a pool for the entire Oracle instance - it is not on a per user base. So, if there are other users of the database, they might contribute the problem. I doubt that any particular query is the cause and I guess that the problem is that the shared pool is undersized.

In case you have some DBA privileges granted for your user, you can check the current shared pool size by running the following query:
`SELECT * FROM v$sgainfo;`

You can increase the size of the shared pool with the following query
`ALTER SYSTEM SET SHARED_POOL_SIZE = 200M;`

Nevertheless, the best solution will be turn to the DBA managing the database (if there is such).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a SAS guy, so, I'll answer your question from the POV of an Oracle DBA, which is what I am.

ORA-04031 means you're running out of space in the shared pool.  With a product like SAS, I'm sure they have a recommended minimum size that the shared pool should be.  So, you should check the SAP installation documentation, and confirm whether your database has a large enough shared pool size set.  (Use `show parameter shared_pool_size` to see what size it's set in your database.)

Second, I'm not familiar with the changes you made, and I'm not sure if that would have an effect on the shared pool utilization.  Perhaps check the SAS documentation on that one.

Third, it could be an Oracle bug.  You should check My Oracle Support for your version of Oracle, and do a search on ORA-04031, with those specific arguments you are seeing in your error message.  If it's a known bug, there may be a patch already available.

If it's none of the above, you may need to open an SR with Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The changes we made increases the buffer between SAS and ORACLE for data transfer. Now we're reading, inserting, or updating 10,000 rows at a time. Can that impact the shared pool?

Comment: Yes, Possibly. Increasing explicitly or implicitly may cause less available shared pool in case you are using ASMM (Automatic Shared Memory Management)